# Getting Selected Items and None Selected

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to find out what items are Selected and anything that is not selected become 0

This is useful for the listbox (or dropdown), anything that is highlighted it mean it has been added (`LEFT JOIN)`

I could not get the SQL to work:

```
SELECT StoreID,  ft.id, name, count(1) as Selected 
FROM `store_food_type` AS sft  
    LEFT JOIN food_type AS ft 
        ON ft.id = sft.food_type_id 
WHERE StoreID = 17633
GROUP BY ft.id

UNION

SELECT 0,  ft.id, name, 0 as Selected FROM food_type AS ft
```

Edit: It did not produce an error, it show the result but `name` are duplicated which I dont want.

It appear like this:

```
+------------+------+----------+----------+
| StoreID    | id   | name     | Selected |
+------------+------+----------+----------+
|      17633 |    1 | Indian   |        1 |
|      17633 |    8 | American |        1 |
|          0 |    1 | Indian   |        0 |
|          0 |    2 | English  |        0 |
|          0 |   25 | Kurdish  |        0 |
|          0 |    5 | Chinese  |        0 |
|          0 |    7 | Turkish  |        0 |
|          0 |    8 | American |        0 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+
```

I want the result to appear like this:

```
+------------+------+----------+----------+
| StoreID    | id   | name     | Selected |
+------------+------+----------+----------+
|      17633 |    1 | Indian   |        1 |
|      17633 |    8 | American |        1 |
|          0 |   25 | Kurdish  |        0 |
|          0 |    5 | Chinese  |        0 |
|          0 |    7 | Turkish  |        0 |
|          0 |    8 | American |        0 |
+------------+------+----------+----------+
```

Comment: In what way does this query fail to work? Does it produce an error, does it run without errors but select no rows or does it return the wrong rows?

Comment: Can a food be selected multiple times by the same store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rows are getting duplicated because of the `UNION` in your query.  In fact, your entire query is backwards - You're trying to get a list of all food types, with an indicator if they're listed for the given store.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT ft.id, ft.name, COALESCE(sft.storeId, 0) as storeId, 
       CASE WHEN sft.storeId IS NOT NULL THEN '1'
            ELSE '0' END as selected
FROM food_type a ft
LEFT JOIN store_food_type as sft
ON sft.food_type_id = ft.id
AND sft.storeId = 17633
```

Although you don't strictly need the `selected` column, as you could simply test whether result column `storeId` was 0 or not.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest approach would be to group the results from your unioned query - like so:

```
SELECT MAX(StoreID) StoreID,  id, MAX(name) name, MAX(Selected) Selected FROM
(SELECT StoreID,  ft.id, name, count(1) as Selected 
 FROM `store_food_type` AS sft  
     LEFT JOIN food_type AS ft 
         ON ft.id = sft.food_type_id 
 WHERE StoreID = 17633
 GROUP BY ft.id
 UNION
 SELECT 0,  ft.id, name, 0 as Selected FROM food_type AS ft) sq
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this answer is any better than the UNION option offered by Mark Bannister, but it is another way to do it.

```
SELECT sft.storeid, ft.id, ft.name, count(sft.storeid) selected
FROM   store_food_type sft
       FULL JOIN food_type ft ON ft.id = sft.food_type_id
WHERE  sft.storeid = 17633 or sft.storeid is null
GROUP  BY ft.id, ft.name, sft.storeid
```

If a food item can only be selected once for any given store, then the "selected" field and the GROUP BY are redundant.

Comment: I think MySQL do not support 'FULL JOIN'